# Spring security substitute for Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, spring-security, passport.js

Is there a substitute for spring security in Node.js. I know of express and passport, but passport provides authentication only. It does not feature "forgot password", "reset password" or crud operations for User and Role.

In other words, passport lacks of a number of commonly used features that are provided by spring security. Is there any Node.js library that provides these features.

Comment: The [sails gitter room](https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails) is also a good place to chat.

Comment: Any recent changes or is passportjs still the best there is for node?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's already mentioned in the question but for anyone else brand new to Node coming here from google and skipping right to the answers like I did:

http://www.passportjs.org

Looks like the most widely used free library that is somewhat comparable to Spring Security, although as the original question points out it is only focused on authentication so it doesn't cover every feature Spring Security has (like role based authorization).

Answer (score 0):

https://auth0.com

https://stormpath.com

and tons of others. Just google "User Managment" node.js

Or at the end of the day write you own. Writing user management is sails takes about an hour and they have integration with things like Mandril for sending forgotten notices.

Comment: special place in hell for people who downvote with no comment.

Answer (score 0):

Although spring security is one of the bests open source security frameworks, the features: "forgot password" and "reset password" aren't implemented by default. You will need to create your views pages and controllers for it. The default User and Role are very basic models of security that are recommended just for a very basic web apps. In most cases you will need to save and manage it in your database and customize all features for reset and forgot password. It can become very complex as you customize your security rules.

For node there are so many options out there, I agree with @KPD the most equivalent of SpringSecurity is [passportjs](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) (18.7k stars on github), although it is much simpler than SpringSecurity, sometimes the secret to success lies in simplicity.